# Reactive getter in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have getter in vuex which returns item from list

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: { arr: {
        1: {name: 'one', attr: true},
        2: {name: 'two', attr: false} 
    },
    mutations: {
        setArrItemName(state, id, name) {
            Vue.set(state.arr, id, name);
        }
    },
    getters: {
        arrItemById(state, getters) => (id) => {
            const item = state.arr[id];
            if(item) return item;
            return {
                 name: 'default', attr: true
            };
        }
    }
})
```

If I output it in template

```
{{ $store.state.arr[1]['name'] }}
```

it updates fine when another part calls

```
this.$store.commit('setArrItemName', 1, 'new name');
```

But if template contains

```
{{ $store.getters.arrItemById(1).name }}
```

Then it's not updated

Problem: this getter is used in different places and I do not want to duplicate this code

```
<template v-if='$store.state.arr[id]'>
    {{ $store.state.arr[id].name }}
</template>
    Default
<template v-else>
</template>
```

If 'default' some day changes, or any other attribute of `default` object then it should be updated in different places.

Answer (score 9):

Try using computed properties for accessing your getters. First, import the `mapGetters` function from Vuex:

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
```

Then, add computed properties for the getters you want as follows:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        getterName: 'your-getter-name-in-store'
    })
}
```

We use a spread operater ( `...` ) while using the `mapGetters` helper; you can read more about why [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html).

Then, in your template, use `{{ getterName }}`.

This also overcomes your problem of code duplication, as you won't need to use `this.$store.getters` everywhere.

Comment: How do pass the id ?
The getter return a function that why vuex can't apply reactive, but work with direct state. Vuex apply reactive on state, but not getter of function.

Comment: @Tobino Sry I could not understand what you are asking. :/

Comment: I didn't well explain, and made mistype... I think, the current problematic is to get sub-set of store with an Id. Your anwser, don't map the Id.
It's more a component design problem than a Store problem.

Comment: @Tobino is this the solution you are saying is correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984484/7814783 ?

Comment: I have try to make a new implementation, with business logic inside Store and get reactive data with computed function.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45265387/2054427
I provide a jsfiddle for more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get reactive on getter which is not pure.
You can create a computed property on local.

Sources : https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/145#issuecomment-230488443

I made some research, and you can use computed function with a getter inside :

```
  computed: {
    arr() {
            return this.$store.getters.arrItemById(this.id);
      }
  },
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtobino/xhf16y3z/5/) example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this typo is just in the question, or in your program too...

***from above***

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: { arr: {
        1: {name: 'one', attr: true},
        2: {name: 'two', attr: false} 
    },
    mutations: {
       ...
```

***should be***

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: { arr: {
        1: {name: 'one', attr: true},
        2: {name: 'two', attr: false} 
      } // missing this closing brace on object arr
    },
    mutations: {
       ...
```

That might explain the getter problem.