# Error in render function: “TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined”, using Vuex and Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I have been dealing with an issue using Vue, Vuex and Vue-Router. I'm building a flash cards app, fetching all the cards on main app creation, then using a Vuex getter to get each card by its id which is passed as a route parameter.

Relevant bits:

App.vue

```
export default {
  components: {
    'app-header': header,
  },
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getAllCards');
  }
}
```

The `dispatch('getAllCards')` is just pulling all the cards from the DB and committing to Vuex `store.js`.

Now I set up a `getter`:

```
getters: {
  cardById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.allCards.find((card) => card._id === id);
  }
}
```

Here is `Card.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <br>
    <div v-if="flipped" class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <pre v-if="card.code"><code class="preserve-ws">{{card.back}}</code></pre>
        <p class="preserve-ws center-vertical" v-else>{{card.back}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <h1 class="title has-text-centered center-vertical is-2">{{card.front}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      card: {},
      flipped: false,
      general_card: false,
      code_card: true,
      random_card: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
  },
  methods: {
  },
  created() {
    this.card = this.$store.getters.cardById(this.$route.params.id);
  }
}
</script>
```

I am getting the TypeError referenced in the title. My understanding is that the `created()` hook happens after `data()` has been set up, so then I can assign `{card}` using the getter. Unfortunately this displays nothing...

If I assign `card()` as a computed property:

```
computed: {  
  card() {
    return this.$store.getters.cardById(this.$route.params.id);
  }
}
```

The card shows, but I still get that error in console. Any idea why? I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737528/error-in-render-function-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-in-vue) and attempted that solution, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question don't have all the premise to get a correct answer.
(We don't know the mutations, the state, neither the actions and we have no clues about app-header component)
So we have to admit some hypothesis :

1. `state.allCards` is an empty `Array` when you mount the component
2. action `getAllCards` is an async function to retrieve or set `state.allCards` with a mutation

`cardById`'s getters, return a function, so vuex can't apply reactive on a function. So if the state change, the getter won't be trigger correctly.
To correct this, use `computed` as you mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44989218/2054427).

But it don't fix the `undefined error`, that from my point of view, is because the getters return `undefined` on mount.

```
getters: {
  cardById: (state) => (id) => {
    var card = state.allCards.find((card) => card._id === id);
    if(card) {
      return card;
    }
    // on undefined return a default value
    return {
      front:'default value'
    };
  }
}
```

You can see the implementation on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtobino/xhf16y3z/5/) with no error on console.

Or you can have a loading state on undefined value for your card component.

If my hypothesis is wrong please provide a jsfiddle to help you.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a derived state based on store state which is to return a filtered card based on a card id. This id is received to your component via the route params. So its better you use a computed property instead of passing  arguments to the store getters

Instead of initializing `card` in data property make `card` a computed property like this:

```
computed:{
    card(){
        return this.$store.state.allCards.find((card) => card._id === this.$route.params.id);
    }
}
```

**Note this**

*If a component needs derived store state based on its own state(in your case rourte params), it should define a local computed property*

Answer (score 1):

I tried everyone else's solutions and they did not work. But I got it to work finally. Here is what worked for me:

I ended up including a top-level:

```
<div v-if="!card"> Loading card... </div>
<div v-else> Rest of card template </div>
```

That seems to have silenced the error. Also, the card lives as a computed property:

```
card() {
  return this.$store.getters.cardById(this.$route.params.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it was throw error in this step

```
getters: {
  cardById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.allCards.find((card) => card._id === id);
  }
}
```

in this step, it can not find _id of cars, because allcards was `null`;

and then you use computed instead, when allcards has been change, it will get again;
you can change code like this

```
getters: {
  cardById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.allCards.find((card) => card && card._id === id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific... The exact error I'm getting is:  

`[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'front' of undefined"`

Your solution doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude in my last comment. Anyway, the error traceback is showing it occurring in `Card.vue` component.

Comment: it has a simple solution, you can use `card && card.front` instead, then will not throw error, but the real reason I can`t find

Comment: For information callback, on find prototype, won't be call on empty array.
So you don't need to check if card exist.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

`$route.params.id` must be `string`, so what is the type of `card._id`? It seems each `card._id` is `number`, I think.

Comment: When doing `typeof card._id`, I am returned a string.